Angular unit tests are failing with Error: NG0205: Injector has already been destroyed. in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js (line 59623
We upgraded our Angular application from version 16 to 18. After the upgrade, our unit tests started failing with the following error:
Error: NG0205: Injector has already been destroyed. in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js (line 59623)
error properties: Object({ code: 205 })
assertNotDestroyed@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:62653:13
get@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:62545:10
get appRef@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:124410:43
findGroupContainer@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:124421:23
show@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:124381:25
setNotificationMessageAndTimeOut@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1077:54
showDanger@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1063:10
showErrorAlert@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1443:27
3354/getData/<@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1367:12
1318/catchError/</innerSub<@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:9619:88
1687/OperatorSubscriber/this._error<@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:9492:16
error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8530:12
_error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8553:24
error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8530:12
_error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8553:24
error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8530:12
_error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8553:24
error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8530:12
_error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8553:24
error@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:8530:12
onLoad@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:25246:22
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:456:171
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:13689:33
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:456:54
runTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:259:37
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:533:26
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:1150:12
globalCallback@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:1191:33
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:1211:12


If you have encountered a similar issue and know the solution, please let us know.

Does it affect all unit tests or just some?  If it isn’t all, then posting an example of the failing tests would be helpful.

Does this answer your question? Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Injector has already been destroyed
